# VisualSVN keeps asking for username and password

Tags: authentication, repository, visualsvn

I rented a server for a month to try some things out. I'm fairly new to servers and everything and trying to learn. I now want to have projects on this server using VisualSVN.

I've installed VisualSVN and added some users to gain access to these repositories. However, everytime I try to login, the authentication window keeps popping up (no matter what I fill in as a username and password).

How do I solve this issue? I'm unable to connect to the repository due to the login window popping up forever after entering the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue! (RESOLVED!!!)

The way I fixed the problem was to change some firewall settings on the server.
If you go into windows firewall settings and make two new "rules" (one for inbound port 443 and one for outbound port 443), you should be good to go. Allow the connection for all networks (public, private, etc.).

After I changed this, I only had to authenticate once and checkout worked fine.

Let me know if this works!!! This problem was killing me.